# Swift Auto Button Resize

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there any way I can automatically adjust my buttons' sizes. On iPhone 6 and 7 it looks really good. When I go to iPhone 8 and up the buttons appear to be too small. I was doing some research and I couldn't really find anything. This is also in Swift and Xcode.

Comment: How does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints that autoresize the button based on text size.

Added images for refrences.

[image]

[image]